# Call C# from native to retrieve a String

Tags: c#, c++, c, compact-framework, pinvoke

I've been stuck on this all day, but it seems like it is not possible, at least using the **compact framework**, to call from the native code a C# method that **returns** a String.

I've seen several exemples about passing data from and to native code, but none of the examples were using return values.

What I would like to do is have a C# function that **returns a string**, so that i can pull that from C# back into C++, i.e call C# from C++ and not the other way.

```
String GetSomeString() { return "foo"; } // C#
```

And call this function from native code which would have a signature like :

```
typedef const wchar_t * (__stdcall * native_func_t)();
```

The problem with this is that it just doesn't work. A NotSupportedException is thrown when I pass my delegate to the native code. However if I replace the String return type by void it works perfectly.

The other solutions would be :

- Call C# from C++ to get the string length, allocate that string on C++, pass it to the C# and make it fill the buffer using unsafe code. But this is dirty and unpractical, so I won't do that.
- Make the C# function call a C++ that will store the result somewhere, and, in the native code, retrieve that result where it was stored once the call to the C# has returned. But this is also very ugly and unpractical.

Do you see another way to do that please ?

Comment: How is the C++ binary loading the C# assembly?  Is this from a callback and the process itself is managed code?

Comment: I'd use a COM BSTR. That said, allocating on the C++ side is a good option. You should not be saying that's no good without a deeper understanding of this topic.

Comment: @ctake Actually it's a Windows Forms application. The C# handles the GUI, but all the rest of the work is done by the native code.

Comment: You still have not explained the mechanism by which your C++ code is called, and the mechanism by which the C# code is called from your C++ code. These are crucial details in an interop question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually it seems that no C# function can return something when called from C++.
**Any return type oher than void** will cause a NotSupportedException to be thrown.

I did not find evidence of this in the MSDN documentation, but after lots of testing it seems that it's how it works, at least with the **compact framework**.

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked already at stackoverflow and other sides.

One stackoverflow post is at [Calling a C# function from a C++ DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552498/calling-a-c-sharp-function-from-a-c-dll).

The linked solutions use CallingConvention.StdCall which is available in CF but you can use CallingConvention.WinApi instead which translates to CallingConvention.StdCall according to this site 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

You can also use other interop techniques like custom messages (SendMessage) between the windows and forms handles.

To expose managed components to C++ use COM (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)